# The service worker navigation preload request was cancelled before 'preloadResponse' settled

Tags: spfx

I'm getting this error after I build and deploy my SPFX project.

The error message goes on to say: 'If you intend to use 'preloadResponse', use waitUntil() or respondWith() to wait for the promise to settle'.

I've tried adding an event listener to wait for the service worker to boot before attempting a preload request:

self.addEventListener( "activate", event => { event.waitUntil( async function () {...

but the event object doesn't have a 'waitUntil' property.

I can see in the debugger that the service worker is coming from: /_layouts/15/odspserviceworkerproxy.aspx.

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Thanks